# Source bash profile when starting interactive Docker session

Tags: bash, docker, exec

Running this opens bash interactively:

> docker exec -it  bash

However, it's not sourcing ~/.bash_profile, ie the bash_profile in the container. I've tried `bash -i` instead of `bash` at the end, but doesn't work. So how to make profile load when entering the container, as it would in a regular interative shell?

Comment: Do you mean *your* `.bash_profile`, or one that is in the container instantiated from the image?

Comment: The one in the container.

Comment: `bash -l` starts a login shell (which sources `.bash_profile`); `bash -i` starts an interactive shell (which would source `.bashrc`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to the container user `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
    . ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

You need to rebuild the image and copy the .bash_profile file too.

Answer (score 0):

-l works, as mentioned by @chepner in comments:

> docker exec -it bash -l